# Curl and php wont work if loaded through browser

Tags: php, api, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to write the response of this call to a file but it will only write if I run it in the cli. When I run it through the browser nothing happens.

```
$url = 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token';

$app_key = '************';
$app_secret = '***********';

$auth_code = '******************************';
$redirect_uri = "https://dev.subely.com/test/";

$rdata = 'code=' . $auth_code . '&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rdata);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $app_key.':'.$app_secret);


$response = curl_exec( $ch );

file_put_contents("/tmp/response.log", $response, FILE_APPEND);
echo "done";
?>
```

Comment: check that `$response` have any values are not through `var_dump ($response);`

Comment: it doesn't. it is just a string of the response.

Comment: didn't get you.  `it is just a string of the response`?

Comment: @Anant it work just fine if i run it in the cli. just not from the webserver

Comment: it is a one line string `{"error_description": "code has expired (within the last hour)", "error": "invalid_grant"}`

Comment: READ THIS:- https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/authenticating-your-app-code-has-expired-error/td-p/105910    Or https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/authenticating-your-app-code-has-expired-error/m-p/105914/highlight/true#M3123

Comment: Might be its SSL verify issue try adding this.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

As default SSL verifier is true

Comment: @Naincy this fixed the problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @isethi Great! Added my answer in comment for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it is the SSL verification problem (default SSL verfication is `TRUE`). As you said its working in CLI but from web it's not working.

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Also, it will good if you check curl execution

```
$response = curl_exec( $ch );

if($response === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
   file_put_contents("/tmp/response.log", $response, FILE_APPEND);
}
```